# Insert data using ajax in laravel 5.4

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am not so much advanced in laravel. I want to insert data using jquery ajax without refreshing I also tried to find solution in google.I know my post looks like zero effort. but I am trying this with some days. here is my code. Thanks in advance.

**recruitment.blade.php**

```
<form id="frm" method="POST" action="{{ url('post_job') }}">
     {{ csrf_field() }}

     <input name="title" type="text" required /> <br>
     <input name="nature" type="text" required /> <br>
     <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" required></textarea>

     <input type="submit" name="" value="Update post">
</form>
```

**web.php(route)**

```
Route::POST('/post_job', 'RecruitmentController@store');
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 $recruitment = new recruitment() ;
 $recruitment->title = $request->get('title');
 $recruitment->nature = $request->get('nature');
 $recruitment->description = $request->get('description');
 $recruitment->save();

 Session::flash('msg','Post done successfully');
 return redirect('/recruitment');
 }
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>

function saveToDatabase()
{

    select = $(this).serialize();
    $('#frm').live("change", function ()
    {
        // POST to php script
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/post_job',
            data:{selected:select}
        }).then(function(data){alert(data)});
    });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    saveToDatabase();
});
```

Comment: Where you sent ajax request ? Can you post your ajax code ?

Answer (score 0):

Controller : 
For Json response, see [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#other-response-types)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 $recruitment = new Recruitment;
 $recruitment->title = $request->get('title');
 $recruitment->nature = $request->get('nature');
 $recruitment->description = $request->get('description');
 $recruitment->save();

 // Session::flash('msg','Post done successfully');
 // return redirect('/recruitment');
   return response()->json( [ 'msg' => 'Post done successfully' ] );
 }
```

In head tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" >
```

Ajax
    For ajax request, see [X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token)

```
<script>
$.ajaxSetup( {
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
} );

function saveToDatabase() {
    $( '#frm' ).submit( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var select = $( this ).serialize();
        // POST to php script
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/post_job',
            data: select
        }).then( function( data ) {
            alert( data )
        } );
        return false;
    } );
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    saveToDatabase();
});
</script>
```

Comment: In inspector element can you check , requesting is sending or not ?

Comment: It does not show any error. just database does not change. i think data does not post.

Comment: In inspector element did you got success code 200 ?

Comment: Now it insert data into database but page also takes refreshing

Comment: did you comment return redirect('/recruitment'); this line ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163134/discussion-between-mujahidur-rahman-mithun-iub-and-alimon-karim).